# Magento 2 - After override Minicart remove link not working

Tags: magento2.4.1, magento2minicart

I am override the minicart,

Source : vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\item\default.html

My code :

app\code\Zero\MinicartQty\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\item\default.html

```
<div class="custom-photo">
            <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
            <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url, title: product_name}" tabindex="-1" class="product-item-photo">
                <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </a>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
            <span class="product-item-photo">
                <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                class="action remove-btn">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

If i click the remove link url added "#".

Answer (score 1):

You have overridden template , but that needs to call in xml file like below then and then whole minicart functionality will work.

You need to create xml file in your modules as per below.

> Please create file checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml under path
> app/code/Zero/MinicartQty/view/frontend/layout

Now need to call your overridden template same as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="item.renderer" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Zero_MinicartQty/minicart/item/default</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now your minicart will work properly.

Comment: Can you please approve my answer as well so it will be helpful for others too. Thanks